# C++ inserting unique_ptr in map

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, stl, unique-ptr

I have a C++ object of type `ObjectArray`

```
typedef map<int64_t, std::unique_ptr<Class1>> ObjectArray;
```

What is the syntax to create a `unique_ptr` to a new object of type `Class1` and insert it into an object of type `ObjectArray`?

Comment: The following MSDN page has some info on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh279676.aspx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446352/what-is-the-difference-between-unordered-mapemplace-and-unordered-mapinsert

Answer (score 95, accepted):

As a first remark, I wouldn't call it `ObjectArray` if it is a map and not an array.

Anyway, you can insert objects this way:

```
ObjectArray myMap;
myMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, std::unique_ptr<Class1>(new Class1())));
```

Or this way:

```
ObjectArray myMap;
myMap[0] = std::unique_ptr<Class1>(new Class1());
```

The difference between the two forms is that the former will fail if the key `0` is already present in the map, while the second one will overwrite its value with the new one.

In C++14, you may want to use [`std::make_unique()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) instead of constructing the `unique_ptr` from a `new` expression. For instance:

```
myMap[0] = std::make_unique<Class1>();
```

Comment: Another option is the emplace member: myMap.emplace (0, new Class1).  Not all libraries support this member, yet, though.

Comment: @milleniumbug I'm pretty sure that's not legal C++. The problem is that the rvalue reference overload of `insert` is a function template, but the braced initializer doesn't give enough information to deduce the template argument.

Comment: @GeoffRomer: There is an overload of `insert` that takes a `const value_type& value` (the first overload in [this list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)).

Comment: @AndyProwl I know, but that overload requires value_type to be copyable, and in this case it isn't.

Comment: @GeoffRomer: Oh, you're right! I got distracted somehow, good catch. Will edit the answer :)

Comment: Doesn't myMap[0] = std::unique_ptr<Class1>(new Class1());  invokes the copy constructor? std::unique_ptr doesn't have one for obvious reasons (pointer is "unique"). Did you compile this?. As @NathanErnst said use emplace.

Comment: @wgodoy, if you're referring to the copy constructor of the unique_ptr, no, it would invoke the move assignment operator.

Answer (score 76):

If you want to add an existing pointer to insert into the map, you will have to use std::move.

For example:

```
std::unique_ptr<Class1> classPtr(new Class1);

myMap.insert(std::make_pair(0,std::move(classPtr)));
```

or similar:

```
myMap[0] = std::move(classPtr);
```

if one wants insert a new or overwrite an already resisting key.

Comment: Also:
myMap.insert({0, std::move(classPtr)});
should work;

Comment: thank you for pointing this out.. I was struggling to push an existing pointer to a map and was at the verge of dropping out and just scrolled down to see your answer.. relieved!

Comment: and if you want to get the value from the map, std::unique_ptr<Class1> c1 = std::move(myMap[0]);?

Answer (score 7):

In addition to previous answers, I wanted to point out that there is also a method `emplace` (it's convenient when you cannot/don't want to make a copy), so you can write it like this:

```
ObjectArray object_array;
auto pointer = std::make_unique<Class1>(...);  // since C++14
object_array.emplace(239LL, std::move(pointer));
// You can also inline unique pointer:
object_array.emplace(30LL, std::make_unique<Class1>(...));
```

Comment: Won't `emplace` just do the same as `insert(move())` ?