# Proper usage of unique_ptr: emplace compiles while insert produces compiler errors (Map of lists )

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr, unordered-map, stdlist

**Context:**

I'm trying to learn smart pointers and I came across a case I don't understand.

I'm creating an `unordered_map` of `unique_ptr<list<int>>`. Declared as following:

```
unique_ptr<unordered_map<uint32_t, unique_ptr<list<uint32_t>>>> mymap;
```

The map and its contents are private data of a class and I want them to be destroyed when the class is destroyed. Therefore I use a `unique_ptr` for the map and for each list.

**Problem:**

When I call `emplace`, like so:

```
mymap->emplace(index, make_unique<list<uint32_t>>());
```

My program compiles just fine. It also works when I call insert creating pair explicitly:

```
mymap->insert(std::make_pair(index, std::make_unique<std::list<uint32_t>>()));
```

However, the following line:

```
mymap->insert({index, make_unique<std::list<uint32_t>>()});
```

produces the following errors (GCC in Linux Ubuntu)):

> /usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const unsigned int; _T2 = std::unique_ptr >]’
>     { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }

From the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446352/what-is-the-difference-between-unordered-map-emplace-and-unordered-map-ins) I learned that the difference between the two methods is that `insert` copies or moves a key-value pair into the container, while `emplace` builds it in place. So perhaps the problem is that I'm not properly using the `unique_ptr`?

**Question: Why the first two calls succeed while the third fails?**

Comment: That's because in the third call you need to be able to construct a `std::unique_ptr` by copy but you are not allowed by design. In any case using an `unique_ptr<list<uint32_t>>` is useless for what you show us of your problem, a simple `unordered_map<uint32_t, list<uint32_t>>` would work in the same way. Actually even a `unordered_multimap<uint32_t, uint32_t>` would suffice.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about `unordered_multimap` I'll look into it.