# STL map: Access violatoin reading location

Tags: c++, virtual

Here is my code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void show() const = 0;
};

class Child : public Base
{
private:
    static const int i = 1;
public:
    virtual void show() const
    {
        cout << i;
    }
};

map<int, const Base &> myMap{
    { 0, Child() },
    { 1, Child() },
};

Base & b = Child();

int main()
{
    b.show();

    myMap.at(0).show(); // This provokes the error

    system("pause>NUL");
    return 0;
}
```

As you see, I'm trying to use a `global`(or `static`) data, which will call some `virtual` functions. When I test `Base & b = Child();` and in `main`: `b.show();`, everything goes well.

But, if I use `map` like above, I will get an error:

> `0xC0000005: Access violatoin reading location 0x00000000`.

I've tried to debug this code and I found that when it arrived `myMap.at(0).show();`, I got this:
[image]

It seems that the table of virtual functions is `Unable to read`...

Then I tried to use the pointer:
`map<int, Base *>` and `{0, new Child()}`.
This works.

So it seems that this error comes from temporary reference.

But I don't know why `b` works. `b` is a temporary reference too.
In my opinion, this `map` contains many `b`.
Why does `b` works whereas `map` doesn't work?

Comment: Define a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Banex While that’s generally a good idea it’s not necessary here, and unrelated to the problem.

Comment: What is your compiler ? My Clang rejects that : map of references, and reference to a temporary ...

Comment: @Banex    I added the virtual destructor for both classes, but I still got the error.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Visual Studio allows references to temporaries as an extension. Not that this means it's a good idea to use it. Code to standards!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a map of references to temporaries. I'm surprised that even compiled

```
map<int, Base &> myMap{
    { 0, Child() },
    { 1, Child() },
};
```

Drop the reference and switch to `unique_ptr`

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Base>> myMap;
```

You can insert elements into this map [using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923748/c-inserting-unique-ptr-in-map). This will prevent [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

You do the same thing again here

```
Base & b = Child();
```

[You cannot hold non-const references to temporary objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826897/why-not-non-const-reference-to-temporary-objects)

Comment: thx. This can compile because I am using the stupid microsoft visual studio.

Comment: Now I try like this: `map<int, const Base &> myMap`. But still, I got the same error.

Comment: `unique_ptr` is the smart pointer. Are you sure that this can solve the error? Seriously for now I even don't know why I get this error ----- I don't think it's because I didn't use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? It should be there in at least 2010.

Comment: Did you `#include <memory>`?

Comment: @Tomas "You do the same thing again here Base & b = Child();"

Comment: It seems that you are talking about reference and smart pointer... I tried like this too: `map<int, const Base &>`, but I still got the same error. I don't know why.

Comment: @SChepurin   thanks guys. About what you are talking about, I totally understand now. But it's not about my problem... I've tried `map<int, const Base &>` but I still got the same error.

Comment: OK, now I know. `map` cant take any temporary value. This is why you tell me to use pointer. thx.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC does allow to affect a temporary to a reference, meaning that `Base & b = Child();` is accepted and correctly processed, even it is **not** standard C++ and is rejected by other compilers (and could be rejected by a later version of MSVC)

But even MSVC does not accept stl containers of references.

So you should either use a `map<int, Base>` (no ref, store a copy of the object), or a `map<int, Base *>` (stores a pointer to the object). In the latter case, **you** must deal explicitely with the destruction of the object. You can also use *smart pointers*, `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` to let the stl cares for automatic destruction.