# Storing passed objects in map by unique_pointer

Tags: c++

I have the following problem in a c++-project at my university:
I want to store some objects of Class1 by using a map.
Because of the design of my project the class that holds the map as a member variable does not create the objects to store in the map. My research on this forum tells me to use unique_ptr to pass those objects.

When combining those two ideas in a test projects for experiments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

typedef std::unique_ptr<std::string> string_ptr;

class Class1 {
public:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, string_ptr> my_unordered_map;

    Class1() : my_unordered_map(){
    }

    void addTo(string_ptr ptr) {
        std::string string = *ptr;
        std::cout << string << std::endl;
        my_unordered_map[0] = std::move(ptr);
    }
};


int main() {
    std::cout << "Process started!"<< std::endl;

    string_ptr ptr;
    ptr = std::make_unique<std::string>("text");

    Class1 cont;
    cont.addTo(std::move(ptr));


}
```

it compiles, but throws a

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>   what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

at runntime.

I also tried changing void addTo(string_ptr ptr) to addTo(string_ptr &ptr) as suggested in other posts, but the problem remained the same.

Now, whats the problem? Is it:
a) A design mistake to not let Class1 create the objects by itself. [C++ inserting unique_ptr in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923748/c-inserting-unique-ptr-in-map) would answer my question in this case.
-- or --
b) Something else my small knowledge of c++ lets me miss?

Sidenote: ofc the objects i want to store in those pointers are not strings.

Comment: Just store strings, not unique_ptrs.

Comment: As mentioned at the end the objects i want to store are not strings.
Or am I missing your point?

Comment: @NewBe Then give us a [MCVE] covering the real situation.

Comment: The point is there is most likely no reason to store `unique_ptr<string>` instead of `string`.

Comment: @user0042: This is an MCVE.

Comment: @Benjamin Well, I thought not regarding OP's real situation. But you're right, we encourage to eliminate the irrelevant stuff.

Comment: @juanchopanza
As far as my knowledge goes:
Storing strings will call the copy constructor to do so. This would require me to rewrite it to avoid long running times for big objects, wont it?

Comment: If you can avoid copy constructing unique_ptrs, you can avoid copy constructing strings.

Comment: As I'm trying to improve my C++ knowledge I again made some testing.
I think I'm not quite getting your point, this is what I did:
http://codepad.org/Fe1bXUPO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
my_unordered_map[0] = std::move(ptr);
```

you are passing `int` as key, but `my_unordered_map` expects `std::string` as key, solution:

```
my_unordered_map[string] = std::move(ptr);
```

---

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>   what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

`std::string` has implicit conversion constructor from `char const*`, it means attempt to construct `std::string` from NULL pointer, what causes this error.

If you would need empty string, do following

```
my_unordered_map[std::string("")] = std::move(ptr);
```

Comment: I doubt using an empty string as key is what the OP actually wants.

Comment: Oh my god.
Not even coding for 10hrs straight is an excuse for this fail.
As i never worked with uniqu_ptrs before i was expecting some complicated reason for this cryptic error massage.
In fact it was just me using 0 instead of a valid string...
Thank you for your time!

Comment: It happens :-) everything ok now ?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with `unique_ptr`. It has nothing to do with your value object at all. It is actually with your key. Unfortunately, the integer literal 0 (and only 0, and not an int variable with the value 0) can be treated as a pointer of any type. And also unfortunately, `std::string` has an implicit conversion constructor from `char const*`. So when you do this:

```
my_unordered_map[0] = std::move(ptr);
```

Since your key type is `std::string`, you are implicitly constructing a `std::string` from an null pointer. That is your error.

Comment: Why did you post same answer?

Comment: @FilipKočica: I didn't. I was writing my answer before yours was posted. And when yours finally was initially posted, it did not explain the situation satisfactorily. You simply said "you can't do this". In fact you can do it. And he did.

Comment: In my opinion it does explain it enough and solved his problem even before you posted it :-)

Comment: @FilipKočica: You're welcome to that opinion. I don't share it.

Comment: OK have a nice day.

Comment: While @FilipKočicas answer solved my problem this is indeed some interesting insight about why it even compiles.
Thank you!