# Inserting unique pointer into a std::map

Tags: c++, c++17, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, unordered-map

I stopped while inserting a *unique pointer* into a `std::unordered_map`.

when I looking for the answer I got a link : [C++ inserting unique_ptr in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923748/c-inserting-unique-ptr-in-map).

I tried that but it will not work for me. Here is my sample what I tried till now.

```
int main()
{
    unordered_map<string,unique_ptr<char[]>> mymap;
    string key = "ac";
    char* ctr = "myvalue";
    unique_ptr<char[]> value = make_unique<char[]>(100);
    memcpy(value.get(), ctr,5);
    mymap.insert_or_assign(key,std::move(value));
    return 0;
}
```

Getting a compilation issue.

Comment: Can you post your compile errors?

Comment: your map key is an integer but `key` is a string? Please post a [mre] with the full code and error message

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `std::vector` instead of `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`? Or, considering your example, `std::string`?

Comment: now that your map key is a string the code compiles (bar missing headers): https://godbolt.org/z/K52XnV. please post a [mre] with the full error message

Comment: Unrelated: Consider not practising [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, always include the *full* and *complete* output in the question itself. And add comments in the [mcve] on the lines where you get the errors. Also please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It's not relevant to your question, but the `memcpy` will truncate the string "myval", and I'm not sure if the array will be default initialized or zero initialized.

Comment: @AlanBirtles You don't need the `#include <map>` in your godbolt example.

Comment: To the OP, if you [edit] your code sample with all the required headers, and include the error message, we'll be happy to re-open this question.  If your attempt has resulted in you working out what the problem was, please let us know.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica yep, I added it because the question said it was using `std::map`, when it didn't compile due to actually using `unordered_map` I forgot to remove it, doesn't change the outcome though

Answer (score 3):

You have your `mymap` taking `int` eger as a key

```
unordered_map<int,unique_ptr<char[]>>  mymap
//            ^^^
```

and the `key` you passing is `std::string`. Obviously, the compiler can not accept this.

You probably meant to have `std::string` as key

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<char[]>> mymap;
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That being said, there is no need of using a smart pointer here, rather simply a

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> mymap;
```

Comment: Updated the code the key is actually  a string sorry

Comment: @DhanasekaranDon If that is the case, can not reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/KabHvY. I would suggest posting complete error message in the question.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use unique pointers in STL containers. The unique pointers just transfer the ownership do not share this.
Probably an undefined behavior will be occurred when you use unique pointers in STLs containers
Copying of containers will leave source containers with invalid data.

Comment: This is simply not true.  You most certainly **can** use unique pointers in STL containers.  Implementing unique pointers could be done in C++89 (see std::auto_ptr), the problem was that you couldn't use them in STL containers.  C++11 introduced rvalue references, std::move, std::unique_ptr, and made it possible.

Comment: Obviously, you cannot *copy* an STL container containing unique pointers, but you can certainly move it.

Comment: Yes, but inside the containers make copies . Invalidation will be generated

Comment: Rubbish.  There are some methods which copy;  they won't compile because std::unique_ptr has no copy constructor or copy assignment operator, but there are always similar methods which move instead.